# I tried to read rtsp stream on python, but can't read it

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, rtsp

My rtsp server url is "rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/" and rtsp stream format is H.264.

When i write a url on chrome at client pc, i can see stream.

but when i execute my python code, i can't see stream and

print this message.

```
[rtsp @ 0x223f0a0] method SETUP failed: 461 Unsupported transport
```

my code of open rtsp is

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/")
```

and my opencv buildinfo is

```
Video I/O:
DC1394:                      NO
FFMPEG:                      YES
  avcodec:                   YES (ver 58.6.103)
  avformat:                  YES (ver 58.3.100)
  avutil:                    YES (ver 56.5.100)
  swscale:                   YES (ver 5.0.101)
  avresample:                NO
GStreamer:                   NO
libv4l/libv4l2:              NO
v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev.h linux/videodev2.h
gPhoto2:                     NO
```

Thank you for your kindly answer.

Comment: which port are you trying to connect? normally for rtsp is 554, if you are able to see it in chrome, then it sounds like not the correct address/port... in some cases, like in some video cams, you need to add to the address /video or something similar. if it is a camera or dvr, you should tell the model for other people to help you better

Comment: @api55 I have "vlc server pc" and "client pc". two pc are directly connected on lan cable(cross cable). if client pc is request stream, vlc server pc execute `vlc -vvv filename --play-and-exit :sout=#rtp{sdp=rdp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8554/} :sout-keep.` port number is fixed 8554. so i can't change it. if i write rtsp url on chrome, video application start and play rtsp. and when i only execute VideoCapture function on python, rtsp stream is not shown. if i execute on python-vlc module, rtsp stream is shown. but, **I want to read rtsp stream on python opencv.**

Comment: all this information is super useful to  get what the problem is... It seems that OpenCV forces TCP connections and VLC uses UDP by default or at least that could be the problem. Try forcing vlc to stream via tcp.

Comment: @api55 thank you. i knew good information, because of you. vlc server program is binary file on vlc server pc. so i think that i can't change udp to tcp. i will have to consider how to solve this problem...

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I think --rtsp-tcp or : rtsp-tcp should work... when you call the vlc from command line

Comment: @api55 Thank you^^. i will tried to do it!

Comment: @api55 I fixed a problem. i changed "tcp" to "udp" on opencv code, and compiled. but show crash frame... hmm

Comment: can you show an example how to changed tcp to udp?

Comment: @Leow Before compile opencv, you can change "tcp" to "udp" in "videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp".